# Which framework to use for Mobile Agents?

Tags: agent, agents-jade

After learning that [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/) does not support Mobile Agent concept but supports only traditional Agent Framework, I was wondering which Framework or technology still uses Mobile Agent Concepts and I can build an application using it. IBM's Aglets could have been, but it is no longer maintained and revised (I think, since I didn't see very active participation in Aglet related forums)

Comment: JADE supports agent mobility - http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/Mobility.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JADE supports agent mobility - http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/Mobility.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mobility-RPC](http://code.google.com/p/mobility-rpc/), it supports code mobility in general, including mobile agents.